# AbstractRoutingDataSource mappers only work with default datasource

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-jdbc

I have 2 datasources. A main one (default) and secondary one. I have an `AbstractRoutingDatasource` implementation which chooses a datasource based on `ThreadLocal` variable and falls back to the default datasource if the `ThreadLocal` is empty. Very vanilla "like-tutorial" situation. In addition to that I have a bit of custom `JdbcTemplate` configuration. It's needed to make some `String`<->`jsonb` conversion work. Problem is that this configuration only takes effect if I fall back to the main datasource. As soon as the `AbstractRoutingDatasource` picks the non-main datasource, I get errors which I should not get because of the custom converters.

**Why this is and what can I do to make the custom configuration work on all datasources no matter what the `AbstractRoutingDatasource` ends up picking?**

`application.yaml`:

```
ds1:
  username: smth1
  password: smth1
  host: smth1
ds2:
  username: smth2
  password: smth2
  host: smth2
```

`RoutingDatasource.kt`:

```
  class RoutingDatasource(
    mainDs: DataSource,
    customDatasources: Map<String, DataSource>
  ) :
    AbstractRoutingDataSource() {

    companion object {
      private val MAIN_DS_NAME = "mainDs"
      public val holder = ThreadLocal<String>()
    }

    init {
      setDefaultTargetDataSource(mainDs)
      setTargetDataSources(customDatasources + (MAIN_DS_NAME to mainDs))
    }

    override fun determineCurrentLookupKey() = holger.get() ?: MAIN_DS_NAME
  }
```

`CustomJdbcConfiguration.kt`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories(
  basePackages = ["my.package"],
  jdbcOperationsRef = "mainJdbcTemplate",
  dataAccessStrategyRef = "mainDataAccessStrategy"
)
class CustomJdbcConfiguration(
  private val readingConverters: List<Converter<PGobject, *>>,
  private val writingConverters: List<Converter<*, JdbcValue>>
) {


  @Bean("ds1")
  fun ds1(): DataSource {
    // build ds1
  }

  @Bean("ds2")
  fun ds2(): DataSource {
    // build ds2
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  fun routingDataSource(
    @Qualifier("ds1") ds1: DataSource,
    @Qualifier("ds2") ds2: DataSource
  ): DataSource {
    return RoutingDataSource(ds1, mapOf("secondary" to ds2))
  }

  @Bean("mainJdbcConversions")
  @Primary
  fun jdbcCustomConversions(): JdbcCustomConversions {
    return JdbcCustomConversions(
      listOf(
        JsonbReadingConverter(),
        JsonbWritingConverter(),
        JsonReadingConverter()
      ) + readingConverters + writingConverters
    )
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  fun jdbcTemplate(dataSource: DataSource, properties: JdbcProperties): JdbcTemplate {
    val jdbcTemplate = JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
    val template = properties.template
    jdbcTemplate.fetchSize = template.fetchSize
    jdbcTemplate.maxRows = template.maxRows
    if (template.queryTimeout != null) {
      jdbcTemplate.queryTimeout = template.queryTimeout.seconds.toInt()
    }
    return jdbcTemplate
  }

  @Bean("mainJdbcTemplate")
  @Primary
  fun namedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate): NamedParameterJdbcTemplate {
    return NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate)
  }

  @Bean("mainJdbcConverter")
  @Primary
  fun jdbcConverter(
    mappingContext: JdbcMappingContext,
    @Qualifier("mainJdbcTemplate") operations: NamedParameterJdbcOperations,
    @Lazy relationResolver: RelationResolver,
    @Qualifier("mainJdbcConversions") conversions: JdbcCustomConversions,
    dialect: Dialect
  ): JdbcConverter {
    val jdbcTypeFactory = DefaultJdbcTypeFactory(operations.jdbcOperations)
    return BasicJdbcConverter(
      mappingContext, relationResolver, conversions, jdbcTypeFactory, dialect.identifierProcessing
    )
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean("mainDataAccessStrategy")
  fun dataAccessStrategyBean(
    @Qualifier("mainJdbcTemplate") operations: NamedParameterJdbcOperations,
    @Qualifier("mainJdbcConverter") jdbcConverter: JdbcConverter,
    context: JdbcMappingContext,
    dialect: Dialect
  ): DataAccessStrategy {
    return DefaultDataAccessStrategy(
      SqlGeneratorSource(context, jdbcConverter, dialect),
      context,
      jdbcConverter,
      operations,
      SqlParametersFactory(context, jdbcConverter, dialect),
      InsertStrategyFactory(operations, BatchJdbcOperations(operations.jdbcOperations), dialect)
    )
  }
}
```

Now if I save an object which Kotlin object has a string field, but in the DB it's a `jsonb` and the `holder` is not set then all works well. If I set the holder to point to non-main database then converters don't work anymore and I get an error like this:

```
ERROR: column "your_column" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 174
```

Even if I flip the datasources, the effect is the same. Always works with the fallback one, never works when it actually routes to a secondary one.

P.S. In my testcase the actual database and the connection properties are exactly the same. So the problem is not on the database side.

Comment: Can you list where you injected a `routingDataSource`  Bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with multiple datasources and custom mappings directly.

Issue was that my end data-sources were Hikari datasources and I forgot to specify the property `data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified` for them. As soon as I did that, everything started working correctly.